# how to Python list Iterate?

Tags: python, odoo

below code shows only estates[0].id in my text box.need to load all values in my field.how to do such a thing.?how to iterate and add those to field value.?

```
def on_change_company(self, cr, uid, ids, company_id, context=None):
    if not company_id:
        return {'value': {
            'bpl_estate_id': False
        }}
    company = self.pool.get('bpl.company.n.registration').browse(cr, uid, company_id, context=context)
    estates = company.estates
    if estates:
        return {
                'value': {
                          'bpl_estate_id': estates[0].id
                          }
                }
    else:
        return {
                'value': {
                          'bpl_estate_id': 0
                          }
                }
```

Comment: You already have an open question in regards to your other issue.  It's best to use that one to get the attention instead of editing an existing question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dictionary, you're only placing `estates[0].id` in your dictionary.  If you want the list of ids, use a list comprehension.

```
if estates:
    return {'value': {'bpl_estate_id': [e.id for e in estates] } }
# rest of code
```

Comment: error comes dear Makoto..
TypeError: str.split is not a function

Comment: What does that have to do with this question? I'm confused.

Comment: please refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590419/openerp-7-many2one-field-with-onchange-event

Comment: refer my code from below link 
https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/tree/openerp